Distinguish $28$ balls to $6$ identical boxes
How many ways can we put $28$ different balls in $6$ identical boxes, when $2$ boxes must contain $4$ balls and $4$ boxes must contain $5$ balls?
The order of the balls inside each box does not matter.
My attempt:
first of all, let us figure out the number of options to distinguish the different balls from identical boxes.
So, ${28\choose4} \cdot {24\choose4} \cdot {20\choose5} \cdot {15\choose5} \cdot {10\choose5} \cdot {5\choose5}$
Then, since the boxes are identical, we need to divide by $6!$ (the options to arrange $6$ boxes).
Thus, $\frac{{28\choose4} \cdot {24\choose4} \cdot {20\choose5} \cdot {15\choose5} \cdot {10\choose5} \cdot {5\choose5}}{6!}$.
Therefore, the answer is $\frac{{28\choose4} \cdot {24\choose4} \cdot {20\choose5} \cdot {15\choose5} \cdot {10\choose5} \cdot {5\choose5}}{4! \cdot 2!}$.
Maybe my answer is not correct. After all, the order between the boxes is unimportant, even though some boxes contain $4$ balls, and some boxes contain $5$ balls.

Since the boxes are identical, the groups you form would be considered unlabeled if with equal # of balls, but you need to know that they become labeled if sizes vary.
So suppose the balls were divided $8-7-6-4-2-1,$ all the groups would automatically  get labeled, and you would not have had to divide at all.
But by the given distribution of balls, they have got divided into two groups which are having different #s of balls, and so form two labeled groups,  say A and B. But the four boxes in A are indistinguishable from each other, and similarly the $2$ boxes in B are indistinguishable from each other.
So the $4$ boxes within A  and the $2$ within B are automatically unlabeled, therefore we divide by $4!2!$

Here is an alternate explanation which requires no division.
Imagine the balls are all uniquely numbered.
Choose the 8 balls being used in the boxes containing four balls a piece.  Among these balls, one will be smallest and can go into a box.  Choose three more from the balls you had chosen to go with it.  The remaining four go into a box together.
All other balls now will be used for boxes with 5 balls in them.  Among these, one will be smallest.  It will go into a box, and choose four more to go with it.  Then among what is left, one will be the smallest.  It goes into a box, and you choose four more to go with it.  Continue in this fashion until all balls are distributed.
$$\binom{28}{8}\binom{7}{3}\cdot \binom{19}{4}\binom{14}{4}\binom{9}{4}\approx 5.318\times 10^{16}$$
This equals the book's answer.
Your answer is incorrect since the "six possible labels" aren't all able to be permuted freely since "Box#1" must get four balls and not five, and so on...

The given answer is correct. The number of ways is
$$
\frac1{2!\cdot 4!}
\left(
\newcommand{\C}[2]{{}_{#1}C_{#2}}
\C{28}4\cdot \C{24}4\cdot\C{20}5
\cdot\C{15}5 \cdot\C{10}5
\right).
$$
Note that $\C{28}4\cdot \C{24}4\cdot\C{20}5
\cdot\C{15}5 \cdot\C{10}5$ is equal to the number of ways to place $28$ balls in six distinct boxes, such that the first two boxes receive four balls, and the other boxes receive five balls. However, you want the boxes to be identical. In order to count identical-box arrangements, we must count the number of distinct-box arrangements which generate the same identical-box arrangement, and divide by that number.
Numbering the balls from $1$ to $30$, an example of a distinct-box placement is
$$
8\;9\;20\;21\; \mid  2\;14\;15\;29\; \mid  6\;7\;10\;28\;30\; \mid  1\;3\;4\;18\;19\; \mid  5\;12\;23\;24\;27\; \mid  11\;17\;22\;25\;26\;
$$
The contents of boxes are separated by vertical bars. Note that the first two boxes have four items, while the last four boxes have five items.
Now, how many ways are there to permute this distinct-box arrangement such that the resulting identical-box arrangement is the same? Certainly, you can permute the first two boxes in $2!$ ways, and you can permute the last four boxes in $4!$. You were asking, why can we not permute all six boxes, generating $6!$ equivalent placements? The reason is because $\C{28}4\cdot \C{24}4\cdot\C{20}5
\cdot\C{15}5 \cdot\C{10}5$ only counts placements such that the first two boxes receive four balls, and the other boxes receive five balls, but if you arbitrarily permute the boxes, then you get arrangements where the box numbers are not in this order. These were not counted by $\C{28}4\cdot \C{24}4\cdot\C{20}5
\cdot\C{15}5 \cdot\C{10}5$, so they should not be factored in.
